# SIMPLE HTML DOM Fatal Error Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Tags: php

Im using Simple HTML DOM Library and im getting error

Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /home/rodingo/public_html/crawler/music.php on line 14

However it is working fine on localhost but causing problem on my Dedicated Server. cURL, fopen everything is enabled but still.

```
 include('includes/simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://mp3skull.com/mp3/'.$mp3name.'.html');
$list = array();
echo $html;
foreach ( $html->find('div#song_html ') as $e ) {  // <-- LINE 14
 $song = array();
    $song['bit'] = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ',$e->find('div', 0)->plaintext);
    $song['title'] = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ',$e->find('div', 1)->plaintext);
    $song['url'] = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ',$e->find('a', 0)->href);
    $list[] = $song;
}
```

Comment: `$html` is the result of `file_get_contents`, so it's a String.

Answer (score 1):

You're using Simple HTML DOM, so I assume you want to use `file_get_html` instead of `file_get_contents`.

`file_get_contents` returns a string, whereas `file_get_html` returns a HTML DOM object.

```
$html = file_get_html('http://mp3skull.com/mp3/'.$mp3name.'.html');
```

Comment: I just checked it, still same :(